# Is there a way to display echo area message over mode line?

Tags: mode-line, echo-area, message

Currently it looks like
[image]

[image]

But this is a bit annoying - as the echo messages changes between single line and multi-lines, the mode-line is moving up and down.

I know I can truncate the message to make it always displayed as single line.

But I think having a way to display the messages over mode-line (using `chilframe` or whatever I guess) is a better solution for me. How can I achieve this? (I'm looking for a general solution not limited to `eldoc` or `lsp-mode`) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the direction of thought could be towards enabling `eldoc-echo-area-prefer-doc-buffer` and configuring `*eldoc*` buffer to show up the way you need it. Maybe with [popper](https://github.com/karthink/popper), or simply

```el
(customize-set-variable
 'display-buffer-alist
 '(("\\*eldoc\\*"
    (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-below-selected)
    (window-height . fit-window-to-buffer))))
```

or something similar (e.g. with an *action function* `display-buffer-in-child-frame`).

For more information on the latter, see [`(info "(elisp) Buffer Display Action Functions")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Display-Action-Functions.html) and [Demystifying Emacs’s Window Manager](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/demystifying-emacs-window-manager).

Comment: That seems to work with `eldoc`. But there are lots of messages using other functions like `lsp--messages` which use `message` inside.

Comment: I'm not an `lsp-mode` user, but would start by looking into the [core options](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/mode/#lsp-signature-function) for configuration. And your comment may be a good suit for creating a follow-up question anyway.